# Creating Layout Programmatically- Two Basic Questions

Tags: java, android, this, nested-class, layoutparams

I have a couple of questions from the following code snippet:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // creating LinearLayout
        LinearLayout linLayout = new LinearLayout(this); //****QUESTION 2*********
        // specifying vertical orientation
        linLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        // creating LayoutParams  
        LayoutParams linLayoutParam = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT); //*****QUESTION 1***
        // set LinearLayout as a root element of the screen 
        setContentView(linLayout, linLayoutParam);
    }
```

1. The base class is ViewGroup.LayoutParams, that is LayoutParams is a
   nested class of ViewGroup. I had also read that it is a static
   nested class. So **why don't we refer to it using the outer class'
   name and dot notation:**

   ```
   ViewGroup.LayoutParams linLayoutParam = new ViewGroup.Layout(...);
   ```
2. In the following statement, **what object is "`this`"?** In the Java
   programming language, the *this keyword in a method refers to the `current` object, i.e. the object to which this method belongs.* But we are not explicitly calling (using an object) the `onCreate()` here in `Android`.

   ```
   LinearLayout linLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... So why don't we refer to it using the outer class' name and dot notation

You seem to be unaware of the [static imports](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) in Java language. Mostly I like the way you are suggesting, i.e. refer to the inner class using the outer class name and the dot like `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`, instead of having an static imports. But, in some cases, if you might have to do that too many times then it's just better to have a static import rather than repeating the class name. You will see this kind of cases a lot while using the unit-testing frameworks like JUnit, which comes with class with a lot of static methods.

> ... In the following statement, what object is "this"?

There in your method, by using the keyword - `this`, you are referring to the current instance of the class in which you have declared/defined the instance method (i.e. the method `@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`).